# Shorter type A German slider coupler

Tags: kegerator

I have a kegerator and have a German beer on draft.  There are limited options in volume so it is a tight fit.  The type a coupler I purchased is too tall by roughly 1/4".  Is there anywhere I can look for a shorter version?

Answer (score 1):

I have a (brand unknown) european-style faucet that came with a 90% elbow as an inlet. The fitting also fits on the beer-out of an A keg coupler, maybe something like that would save you some room?

There are also low-profile 90° elbows out there, a quick web search will show you who sells them.